Google Business Profile API granted but not working?
We just got access to the GBP API. We are testing some stuff in Playground with our own OAuth credentials. The API is enabled and we have quota. However, we keep getting this error:
{
  "error": {
    "status": "NOT_FOUND", 
    "message": "Method not found.", 
    "code": 404
  }
}


Tested this URL:
https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{accountId}/locations/{locationId}/reviews/
What are we missing? The code is from documentation. I'm a Workspace user as well. Everything looks correct on cloud.
Tried everything... Need to make this work for our reputation management SaaS.

Google Mybusiness v4 has been deprecated.
use instead
 GET https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=accounts/*}/locations

you can read more Google Business Profile APIs

Thank you for your reply.
As you can see, we are using the mybusiness.googleapis.com method for fetching reviews. The API you have shared is correct, but we are calling a different method. According to Google's documentation, the My Business API currently uses version 4 (v4).
Please check:
https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data#list_all_reviews

I exactly mean the API you are using has been deprecated, the link you have shared is the old one
